# can not see the relation in the array with orm

Tags: lithium

I am trying to see why cant I see in my /hospitals/index the groups that they belong to. I am following this article http://li3.me/docs/manual/models/relationships.md

However, I dont see the associative array of group included to hosital.
below are my view model and controllers

```
//hopsitals model

namespace app\models;

class Hospitals extends \lithium\data\Model {

    public $belongsTO = array('Groups');

}
```

and here is groups model

```
//groups model
namespace app\models;
class Groups extends \lithium\data\Model {
    public $hasMany = array('Hospitals');
}
```

then my hospitals controller looks like this

```
//hospitals controller
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\hospitals;
use app\models\groups;

class HospitalsController extends \lithium\action\Controller {

    public function index() {
        $hospitals = Hospitals::find('all', array(
            'with' => 'Groups'
        ));
        $hospitals = $hospitals->to('array');
       // $hospitals = $hospitals->to('json');
        return compact('hospitals');
    }

    public function add() {
        if($this->request->data) {
            Hospitals::create($this->request->data)->save();
        }
          }

        $groups = Groups::find('all');

        $groupsList = array();
        foreach($groups as $group) {
            $group = $group->to('array');

            $groupList[$group['_id']] = $group['group_name'];
        }

        $this->set(compact('groupList'));

    }
}
```

and here is groups controller.

```
namespace app\controllers;
use app\models\groups;

class GroupsController extends \lithium\action\Controller
{

    public function add()
    {

        $group = Groups::create();
        $success = false;

        if ($this->request->data && $group->save($this->request->data)) {
            $success = true;
        }
        return compact('group', 'success');
    }

    public function index(){
        $groups = Groups::find('all', array(
            'with' => 'Hospitals'
        ));
        $groups =  $groups->to('array');
        return compact('groups');
    }
}
```

so a group can have multiple hospitals. but I ma not seeing in the var_dumps what groups (if any) the hospitals belong to or if there are any hospitals in a group.

Any help will be appreciated.

here is mongo db

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54bd8a198dcfba8a29000001"), "group_id" : "54bd7e448dcfba5229000000", "hospital_name" : "test3", "hospital_subtitle" : "test3", "hospital_add_1" : "test3", "hospital_add_2" : "test3", "hospital_city" : "test3", "hospital_state" : "test3", "hospital_zip" : "test3", "hospital_phone" : "test3", "hospital_fax" : "test3", "hospital_description" : "test3", "callcenter_agent_approval" : "test3", "hospital_site" : "test3", "mdpocket_approval" : "test3", "hospital_active" : "test3", "facebook" : "test3" }
> db.groupss.find()
> db.groups.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54bd7e448dcfba5229000000"), "group_name" : "group 123", "group_num" : "00001", "group_desc" : "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of \"de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum\" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, \"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..\", comes from a line in section 1.10.32.", "group_logo" : "n/a", "group_address1" : "40 abourne road", "group_address2" : "n/a", "group_city" : "NM", "group_state" : "NM", "group_zip" : "00022", "group_website" : "test.com", "group_facebook" : "facebook.com/groups", "group_phone" : "212344455", "group_fax" : "345345345434", "group_contact_name" : "Asim", "group_subs_status" : "Active", "group_subs_start_date" : "2014-11-17", "created" : "n/a", "modified" : "n/a" }
>
```

I did a var_dump on group _relations and I get

```
array (size=1)
  'Hospitals' => 
    object(lithium\data\model\Relationship)[34]
      protected '_classes' => 
        array (size=1)
          'entity' => string 'lithium\data\Entity' (length=19)
      protected '_config' => 
        array (size=10)
          'link' => string 'embedded' (length=8)
          'fieldName' => string 'hospitals' (length=9)
          'name' => string 'Hospitals' (length=9)
          'type' => string 'hasMany' (length=7)
          'from' => string 'app\models\Groups' (length=17)
          'key' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'to' => string 'app\models\Hospitals' (length=20)
          'fields' => boolean true
          'constraints' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          'init' => boolean true
      protected '_autoConfig' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected '_methodFilters' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

thanks

Comment: Relationships aren't implemented for Mongo (mostly because there's little point without joins), but it's easy enough to just add getter methods for related data.

Comment: yep thats what I am planning on doing.